# How to install ThreadScope on GHC 6.12 in Ubuntu

Tags: haskell, glade

I've try to install treadScope on my computer for Haskell parallel profiling, I'm using Ubuntu 10 and GHC 6.12. The problem it that I unfortunatlly came out with the following problem. I can't install glade, and the command *pkg-config -modversion libglade2.2* return an error, which mean that the glade's **.pc** file is not found by the system. How can I fix this problem on ubuntu,

Thank you a lot for any answer

**More details**

here is the error message return by the command *cabal install threadscope*

Linking /tmp/glade-0.12.02992/glade-0.12.0/dist/setup/setup ...

Configuring glade-0.12.0...

setup: The pkg-config package libglade-2.0 version >=2.0.0 is required but it
could not be found.

cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:

glade-0.12.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was: ExitFailure 1

threadscope-0.1.2 depends on glade-0.12.0 which failed to install.

And here is the error message return by the command _pkg-config --modversion libglade-2.0

Package libglade-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libglade-2.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'libglade-2.0' found

Thanks for your reply

Comment: Do you have `libglade2-dev` installed?  Please post error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lot of thanks to TomMD,

I've install libglade2-dev and thinks goes well

thanks a lot for your reply